# Printing label for Tf Lite model Image Classification

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, image-classification

I am working on a Image Claasification TF Lite model to detect mask or no mask from human faces using this [link](https://heartbeat.comet.ml/running-tensorflow-lite-image-classification-models-in-python-92ef44b4cd47). I followed the link and trained an image multi class classification in vertex AI and downloaded the TF lite model. The labels of the model are "mask" and "no_mask". In order to test the model, I wrote the following code:

```
interpret= tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path="<FILE_PATH>")
input= interpret.get_input_details()
output= interpret.get_output_details()

interpret.allocate_tensors()

pprint(input)
pprint(output)

data= cv2.imread("file.jpeg")
new_image= cv2.resize(data,(224,224))

interpret.resize_tensor_input(input[0]["index"],[1,224,224,3])
interpret.allocate_tensors()
interpret.set_tensor(input[0]["index"],[new_image])
interpret.invoke()
result= interpret.get_tensor(output[0]['index'])

print (" Prediction is - {}".format(result))
```

Using this code for one of my image is giving me the result as :

```
[[30 246]]
```

Now I want to print the label in the result as well. For example:

mask: 30

no_mask: 46

Is there any way I can implement this?

Please help as I am new to TF Lite

Comment: Have you seen the model with netron.app to verify that it is outputing 2 labels? The output doesn't seen right to me.

Comment: I checked in the netron app. It is outputting two labels. The array is [1,2].

Comment: So what is [[30 246]] ?

Comment: [[30 246]] are the output of the prediction. I submitted an image for prediction of mask or no_mask so either of the value is mask prediction and the other one is the no_mask prediction. I need to find out which is what i.e label should also be printed. Eg: [[ Mask:30, No_mask: 246]]. Note: the values 30 and 246 are intermediate result. The confidence value or the probability will be calculated by dividing these values by 255. So the actual probabilities will be: [[ 0.11, 0.96]]

Comment: I think you have already answered this yourself. Use python to get the values. The labels are whatever you have set at the beggining. Check the original model to see what is 30 and what is 246.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself. The .tflite model downloaded from Vertex AI contains the label file called 'dict.txt' that contains all the labels. Check the GCP doc [here](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/export/export-edge-model#output-files). To get this label file we first need to unzip the .tflite file which will give us the dict.txt. For more information, check out [the tflite documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert/metadata#model_with_metadata_format) and [how to read associate file from the models](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert/metadata#read_the_associated_files_from_models).

After that I executed the following code taking reference from [the github link label.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/examples/python/label_image.py):

```
import argparse
import time

import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import tensorflow as tf
interpret= tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path="<FILE_PATH>")
input= interpret.get_input_details()
output= interpret.get_output_details()

interpret.allocate_tensors()

pprint(input)
pprint(output)

data= cv2.imread("file.jpeg")
new_image= cv2.resize(data,(224,224))

interpret.resize_tensor_input(input[0]["index"],[1,224,224,3])
interpret.allocate_tensors()
interpret.set_tensor(input[0]["index"],[new_image])
interpret.invoke()
floating_model= input[0]['dtype'] == np.float32
op_data= interpret.get_tensor(output[0]['index'])
result= np.squeeze(op_data)

top_k=result.agrsort()[-5:][::1]
labels=load_labels("dict.txt")
for i in top_k:
   if floating_model:
      print('{:08.6f}: {}'.format(float(result[i]), labels[i]))
    else:
      print('{:08.6f}: {}'.format(float(result[i] / 255.0), labels[i]))
```